# What are the types of "Ge"-sounds in the East Slavic languages?

Tags: фонетика

I heard the Russian Г (твёрдое Г) *(год)*, Russian palatalized Г (мягкое Г) *(мозги)* and Belarusian Г *(гэты)*. Does this list describe all types of "Г"-sounds in Eastern Slavic languages?

More precisely:

1. - Do some (especially borrowed) words in the Belarusian language use the "Russian Г" sound *(Гузік)*?
   - It is considered outdated to use the letter Ґ *(Ґузік)* for that sound, isn't it?
2. - Do Ukrainian Г and Belarusian Г have the same pronunciation?
   - Do Ukrainian Ґ [Belarusian Ґ] and Russian Г have the same pronunciation?
3. There is "alternative sound of Г" in some words of the Russian language *(ага, угу, бог, господь)*. What type of Г is it?

I hope such "barbaric" description of sounds is understandable. Ideally, the answer should use and explain all kinds of Ge through the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56159/discussion-on-question-by-yalov-what-are-the-types-of-ge-sounds-in-the-east-sl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2. - > Do Ukrainian Г and Belarusian Г have the same pronunciation?

     In general — **no**.

     Belarusian Г is usually considered to be [voiced velar fricative [ɣ]](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_fricative).

     Exact nature of Ukrainian Г is debated. Some claim it is [voiced glottal fricative [ɦ]](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_glottal_fricative), while others — [voiced pharyngeal fricative [ʕ]](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_pharyngeal_fricative) (both sample sounds in Wikipedia represent Ukrainian Г badly). Also pronunciation of Ukrainian Г may vary, depending on word etymology and speaker's dialect, sometimes it may turn into Belarusian-like [ɣ]. But most agree that in the "canonical" dialects of Ukrainian language in majority of words (excluding cases of borrowed words when it's sometimes pronounced as [ɣ] just because of mimicking pronunciation of original language, e.g. Greek) it differs from Belarusian Г.

     <sup>(However in mid-schools Ukrainian children are usually taught that Ukrainian Г is a voiced counterpart of the Х [[x]](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative). Not because it really is (it is not; Belarusian Г [ɣ] is), but rather because no other Ukrainian consonant fits this role better — and such a simplified view is enough for mid-schools.)</sup>

     <sup>(Please don't be confused by the "[ɦ] vs. [ʕ]" dilemma. The "[ɦ] vs. [ʕ]" is more theoretical question about *right classification* of the sound, not about right pronunciation. Per my individual perception, Wikipedia samples for both [ɦ] and [ɣ] represent Ukrainian Г inexactly, and for [ʕ] — even worse (thus Ukrainian Г for me sounds like something between Wikipedia samples for [ɦ] and [ɣ]). Real pronunciation of Ukrainian Г can be heard, for example, in the [O. Avramenko's lessons](http://%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80/11/12/page/21/) — he begins almost every his lesson with "доброГо дня".)</sup>
   - > Do Ukrainian Ґ [Belarusian Ґ] and Russian Г have the same pronunciation?

     In general — **yes**. It is [voiced velar stop [ɡ]](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_stop).

   More info: [Ukrainian phonology](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_phonology).
3. > There is "alternative sound of Г" in some words of the Russian language *(ага, угу, бог, господь)*. What type of Г is it?

   The ["Russian phonology"](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology) Wikipedia article says it's either [ɡ] (strict), or [ɣ] (like Belarusian).

   While the ["Ge (Cyrillic)"](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge_(Cyrillic)) Wikipedia article says it's region-dependent: /ɡ/ generally, /ɣ/ in the Southern Russian dialect and may be /ɦ/ in the regions bordering Belarus and Ukraine.

---

**UPD**. by @yalov

1. > - Do some (especially borrowed) words in the Belarusian language use the "Russian Г" sound (Гузік)?
   > - It is considered outdated to use the letter Ґ (Ґузік) for that sound, isn't it?*

   Consensus on this has never been reached, There are 3 answers:

   - Jan Stankievič promoted both the reintroduction of the practice of pronouncing Latin [g] in newly assimilated words, and the adoption of the letter Ґ to represent it.
     [Станкевіч Я. Гук "Ґ" у беларускай мове. Бацькаўшчына, 1956](https://arche.by/item/4803)

     Also, original norm of [Taraškievica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tara%C5%A1kievica) (1918) doesn't include Ґ.
     Ґ were discussed at Belarusian Academical Conference (1926), where some changes of the Belarusian alphabet were proposed, but never were implemented; and Ґ is included in modern normalization of Taraškievica (2005).
   - [Зычны гук Г выбухны](https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%93_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%8B) has the list of words with [g], but uses Г-letter for that.
   - [g] tends to move into [ɣ], and it was done completely for the last 100 years. So there isn't [g] and Ґ.

Comment: There is some info [Ghe_with_upturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghe_with_upturn) and [Зычны_гук_Г_выбухны](https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зычны_гук_Г_выбухны). Belarusian Ґ-sound is **voiced velar plosive**. It is not Russian **voiced velar stop** [g], right? So Bel Ґ-letter is deprescated; Bel Ґ-sound is still on, but it tends to move into something called "fricative Г/pharyngeal Г", IRL into [ɣ]

Comment: @yalov, I'm absolutely not expert in that. But English Wikipedia article for "voiced velar plosive" **redirects** to "voiced velar stop". So I suppose them to be same-or-close things.

Comment: @yalov, just to clarify: for me Ukrainian Г sounds **between** [the Wikipedia example for \[ɣ\]](//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Voiced_velar_fricative.ogg) and [the one for \[ɦ\]](//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Voiced_glottal_fricative.ogg) — depending on word position and etc (and [the one for \[ʕ\]](//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Voiced_pharyngeal_fricative.ogg) is unrelated at all). But it's just personal impression (not necessarily objective). And it doesn't necessarily relate to exact nature of the sound.

Answer (score 6):

This question comes from a wrong assumption that these consonants are similar. The seemingly similar Cyrillic letters `Г` and `Ґ` are the ones to blame.

The reality is quite different.

---

#### Theory

First off, as a general rule, the spoken language is always the key, and the writing only "encodes" the real, actual sounds of each particular language. It is a good idea to keep in mind that the writing can spoil the entire picture. Take the vowel `о`. Ukrainian `о` is almost always different to the Russian counterpart, despite the fact is "encoded" with the same symbol.

Leave alone the fact that even within the same language it can be tricky: there are **three different vowels** in Russian word *молоко* `[mə lɐ 'kɔ]` (or even **five** if you consider the dialectal `[mə ɫʌ 'ko]`), for example — all five "encoded" with `о`.

---

#### Phonemes in question

Returning back to `G`-consonants,

Ukrainian `Г` is "voiced **glottal** fricative",
Ukrainian `Ґ` is "voiced **velar** stop" (just like the Russian `Г`), and
Belarussian `Г` is "voiced **velar** fricative"

So they belong to three different classes, having very few in similar.

This image shows (pretty schematic) the location of `glottis` and `velum`:

[image: Speech organs]
(image courtesy of [The Marine English Forum](https://themarineenglishforum.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/speech-organs-and-manner-of-articulation/))

---

#### Similar Phonemes in Slavic Languages

This also implies the answer to te question,

> Does this list describe all types of "Г"-sounds in Eastern Slavic languages?

The answer is, there is no such thing as "Г"-sounds. One may or may not consider various consonants a "Г"-sound or not, depending on many factors. Take the following examples:

- Full glottal stop `ʔ`. If you speak Russian, this is the phoneme in word `не-а` — why not?, it is also glottal;
- Voiceless velar fricative `x` (as in Ukrainian *хліб*) — why not?, it differs from Belarusian `Г` only by being voiceless.

See, if we replace the term of "Г"-sounds with something more formal (e.g., "glottal" or "fricative"), we automatically get the full list of languages having this phoneme, **regardless of how they are written**.

---

#### Phone-to-Phoneme

Yet another consideration is for [mapping phones to phonemes](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3637/1009). Each phoneme may be pronounced differently by different speakers (in other words, they produce different *phones*), but a listener would *map* these phones to the same *phoneme* to decipher the word.

---

#### Further reading

- The Wikipedia page for [IPA/Pulmonic consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Pulmonic_consonants) contains a nice diagram of the majority of consonants in human languages. They also have [Chart with Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_pulmonic_consonant_chart_with_audio).